# hash table program that will take the first character of a string

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

I need to make a hash table program that will take the first character of a string in a small case letter and modulo the ASCII with the size of the hash table that the user input. Where should I input the size other than in the main?

These are my current codes. In this code, I ask the user to input the size in the main module function but I am confused about how to use it in on every function besides main. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>




struct data
{
    char name [100];
    char age[2];
    struct data *next;
};

struct data *chain[size] = {NULL};

struct data* insert(char name[], char age[]){
    struct data *curr = (struct data*) malloc (sizeof(data));
    strcpy(curr->name, name);
    printf("input name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",strcpy(curr->name, name));
    printf("input age: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", strcpy(curr->age, age));
    curr->next = NULL;
    return curr;
};


int main(){
    int n;
    char name[100]; 
    char age[2];
    char firstChar;
    int key;
    int index = 0;

    printf("input the number of hash table: ");
    scanf("%d", &n); getchar();
    printf("\n");


    int option;
    do{
        printf("=== Option Menu ===\n");
        printf("1. insert data\n");
        printf("2. delete data\n");
        printf("3. search data\n");
        printf("4. view data\n");
        printf("5. exit\n");
        printf("input option: ");
        scanf("%d", &option); getchar();

        switch(option){
            case 1:
                insert(name,age);
                break;
        }
    }while(option!=5);
}
```

Comment: Make it global.

Comment: `age` is too small, unless you only use ages < 10: add room for the terminating null character

Comment: so i just need to put the int n; in global scope?

Comment: What is the purpose of `scanf(" %[^\n]s",strcpy(curr->name, name));` And yes, put `n` in the global scope.

Comment: i need to use linked list in this hash table program. but it gives me [Error] array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token?

Comment: The lists are normally in the hash entries. The hash table is not a linked list (it is a table, hence array).

Comment: can i make the size of hashtable dynamic ? or is it supposed to be constant only?

Comment: Generally constant size hash tables suffice, though dynamic is possible (but much harder). Note that the lists, which manage collisions of the hash table, are dynamic in size.

Answer (score 0):

> can i make the size of hashtable dynamic ?

Yes, you can, and you even need to, since you wrote "*I need to make a hash table program … with the size of the hash table that the user input*". In order to do that, don't define `struct data *chain[size] = {NULL};` but `struct data **chain;` and after input of `n` in `main` do

```
    chain = calloc(n, sizeof *chain);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But why do I get an error message saying [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'data**' [-fpermissive]?

Comment: You get this error because you use a C++ instead of a C compiler.

Comment: By the way, you have to write `sizeof (struct data)` instead of `sizeof(data)`.